# How to create a multiple new Hashmaps using java 8 streams?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, functional-programming

I want to achieve the below snippet using  java 8  streams.Any answers would be appreciable.I need to set different values for the same key 'amount'.so that i am creating new hashmap inside a loop.It will be like **[{amount=100},{amount=200}]**.

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList('', '', '');
List<Map<String,Object> finalList = new ArrayList();
for(String dataIterate : data) {
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap();
    map.put("amount",dataIterate);
    finalList.add(map);
}
```

Comment: And what are you going to do with all those `HashMap`s? Simply let the garbage collector release them?

Comment: Firstly this this code doesn't compile. Secondly, you try to add one key with different value? Finally, what you are going to do with map? Not clearly

Comment: and why not a `Pair` or `SimpleEntry` for a key value instead of a `Map` with a single entry

Comment: @Eugene Or a custom class with 2 fields

Comment: I want to set different values for the same key 'amount'.so that i am creating new hashmap  inside a loop.It will  be like [{amount=100},{amount=200}].I for to add  list in that  loop

Comment: undoubtedly yes @Eugene.Thanks a lot for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you are asking for,

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = data.stream()
        .map(s -> Stream.of(s).collect(Collectors.toMap(s2 -> "amount", Function.identity())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Get each element in the source, create a `Map` with the given constant key and that elements value. Finally collect them into a `List`

Comment: Ravi,am getting compilation error like cannot infer type arguments

Comment: In which line? It's working fine for me.

Comment: Use this as data source, `List<String> data = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d")`

Answer (score 2):

```
 data.stream()
     .map(dataIterate -> {
           Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap();
           map.put("amount", dataIterate);
           return map;
     })
     .collect(Collectors.toList()) // or any other terminal operation you might need
```

But it's really unclear why not a *simpler* `SimpleEntry` or `Pair`, or anything else that can hold a key/value instead of a `Map` with a single Entry

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene.This is what  ,am expected!!.

Comment: `.map(dataIterate -> Collections.singletonMap("amount", dataIterate))` or, if it has to be a `HashMap`, `.map(dataIterate -> new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap("amount", dataIterate)))`

Comment: Thank you @Holger.I will try

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follow, using `initialization block` for the `Map` :

```
List<Map<String, String>> map = 
           data.stream().map(data -> new HashMap<String, String>(){{put("amount", data);}})
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[***`Workable Demo`***](https://ideone.com/nt7pNr)

---

But to store multiples values for the same keys, you'd better use a `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: This is prone to memory leaks, as this subclass of `HashMap` will keep a reference to `data` even if you remove the entry, as well as a reference to the outer instance if you use this in a non-static context.

Comment: @Holger nore sure to understand, how it is so different of what you proposed as comment below ?

Comment: The curly braces create an anonymous inner class subclassing `HashMap` and capturing the variables used inside the body (i.e. `data`). Further, unlike lambda expressions, anonymous inner classes always capture a reference to the outer `this`, even if it’s not used. This is entirely different to performing a method invocation to `Collections.singletonMap("amount", dataIterate)` which will just return an instance of a map containing the specified mapping. See also [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/2711488)…

Comment: Thank u @azro.This is the thing i expected.